# How can I filter dictionary [[String:String]]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

I have a big dictionary in my App looks like that:

```
var data = [["type":"Sport", "model":"R6"],["type":"Enduro", "model":"Tenerre"],["type":"Chopper", "model":"Intruder"]]
```

which I would like to sort in `UISearchController` using this function `func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)`

inside this function up I would like to filter my array by "type" not using `for` but `filter(includeElement: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool)` but I recive an error `Cannot convert value of type String -> Bool to expected argument type ([String:String]) -> Bool`

I am doing something like this:

```
self.data.filter({ (type: String) -> Bool in
        return true     
    })
```

how should I do it correct?

Answer (score 1):

`data` has this type `[[String:String]]`. In other words is an `Array of [String:String]`.

So the parameter of the closure you pass to `filter` must have this type: `[String: String]`.

You can use the following code and replacing my simple `return true` with your logic.

```
let filteredData = self.data.filter { (dict:[String:String]) -> Bool in
    return true
}
```

> Please keep in mind that `dict` is the *i-th* element of the Array `data`.

Comment: You can simplify like this : `self.data.filter { $0["type"] == "yourFilter" }`

Comment: Absolutely true! In my code I used the "extended version" in order to make clear that the param of the closure is a `[String:String]`. But thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @ebluehands could you explain me what does it mean `{ $0["type"] == "yourFilter" }` especially "$0"

Comment: @PiterPan $0 is the `i-th` element being processed. So `{ $0["type"] == "yourFilter" }` means `filter the list and returns only the dictionaries where the value associated to the "type" key is equals to "yourFilter"`

Comment: @PiterPan: Please test my answer and if it does solve your problem accept it.

Comment: @appzYourLife I would like to use it in my SerachBar in this function: `func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)`, so in `Your Filer` do I should call `searchText`? Whole code looks like that: `let filteredData = self.data.filter{$0["category"] == searchText  ]}`. Is it ok?